# Atomic writes with Ghostscript output devices

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm using Ghostscript to convert PDF pages to PNG using the following on the command line:

```
gs -dDOINTERPOLATE -sDEVICE=pnggray -r200x200 -o 'page%%d.png' filename.pdf
```

My intent is to take in large PDFs and do other work with the PNGs as they are built, cleaning them up after I'm done. However, it seems that the output PNGs aren't generated atomically -- that is, they become available before they're complete. Is there a way to get Ghostscript to generate these files atomically, or some way I can access them as the command runs without encountering incomplete files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. Ghostscript opens the file for writing immediately that the page begins. It write the data either in one large lump when the page is complete, or in a series of horizontal stripes (at high page sizes or resolutions).

Since it might be writing the page in a series of bands, it has to open the file up front.

You could write an application around Ghostscript using the API, that will produce a callback on page completion which you could then use to trigger your other processing.